# Routing angular 2 e laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, angular, routing

Criei um sistema inicial (crú) de laravel 5.3 e consegui implementar o angular 2.0... coloquei pra visualizar o app.component no welcome.blade e funcionou normal...
Tenho dúvidas de como fazer o routing com o angular 2 no laravel 5.3...
Gostaria de fazer que em cada modulo, ex: usuários fosse usado o angular no front end... por ex: no index dos users, tivesse a pagina que fazia uma solicitação "ajax" para o laravel retornar o json da listagem do banco de dados e assim por diante...
Já li mto artigo em inglês, mas só acho sobre angularjs 1.

Comment: https://angular.io faça o getting started, vai te ajudar bastante

Comment: Ja fiz, inclusive fiz só o routing do angula 2 e ficou beleza, o problema é a integração com o laravel

Comment: Você esta usando o pra prover uma API Rest ou para prover páginas?

Comment: Coloque o seu código na pergunta, um exemplo minimo seria legal.

Comment: Então, na verdade, queria um caminho pra estudar esse assunto, tenho varios modulos, um deles é cadastro de usuarios(ja esta feito em blade), mas gostaria de fazer na parte de usuarios uma sigle page em angular que fizesse as solicitações Http via angular

Comment: Tipo o create users, delete, etc... ja esta tudo feito os controller models etc, só queria inplantar o angular em single page

Comment: @FernandoHeriqueRubimPioli entendi ... pena não sei nada sobre Angular, agora sobre Laravel eu sei...